# JavaScript object reference giving undefined value

Tags: javascript, error-handling, javascript-objects, undefined, undefined-behavior

I am very new to javascript and I was making a rock, paper, scissor game, but the below lines of code is giving me undefined value can someone explain me in simple words why console log is giving me undefined as output .

```js
let userval = prompt("enter R,P,S");
const object={
  R : "ROCK",
  P : "PAPER",
  S : "SCISSOR"
};
console.log(object.userval)
```

I want the console to log "ROCK" when i enter R in prompt and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to reference `userval` as a property on the `object` that you defined, when really you want to be using the value to look up a property.

Perhaps try `console.log(object[userval])`?

It is helpful to set debug breakpoints in the dev tools to examine how objects are constructed as well, and to experiment with different calls in the console.

Answer (score 0):

`object.userval` is equivalent to `object['userval']`. You need to use `object[userval]` in order to access the `userval` variable.